# Validating form input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, select

### I have an html form with a text box that I want to change to a drop-down select field. I have done so, but because this field is validated by a js file, the modified form kicks out an error whenever submitted. I know what js file to edit and where to look but I am not sure exactly what to do. I will show below the original code as well as the changes I have made for the html file, and I'll also show what I have found in the js file. Thank you for any help.

Original HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="tag" value="{$tag}" placeholder="{$lng->edit_tags}">
```

Modified HTML:

```
<select name="tag" style="width: 200px;">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
```

Original js code:

```
// Validate the tags input
var tag_min = 0;
var tag_max = 0;
var upload_tags = $('input[name="tag"]').val();
if(upload_tags == 0) {
    tag_min = 1;
}
if(upload_tags.split(',').length > 30) {
    tag_max = 1;
}
```

Where I am clueless is how to make the js file validate the select field as it did with the text field.

Comment: What do you need that validation for? You specify the options in select anyway, so not sure what you are trying to do. Would you like just to test whether something was selected? Or whether the given option is lower or greater than X value?

Comment: I honestly do not know. When we submit the form (since the changes), we get an error. I asked someone to look at the code and I was told the issue was with the javascript file. Whatever is selected in the HTML form should be passed on the the database, and that is not happening since we changed the HTML form code.

Comment: I think you could remove the entire JS validation, as it's redundant, because in the previous example (I mean the one with input) you could pass multiple tags, therefore the code needed to check if X amount is passed. Here there will be only one tag selected, so remove the validation and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I removed the whole section for validation and same error was the result. I may see if the developer can advise me on it.